# Is there a way to get the hash for a picture stored in Google Photos without downloading the file?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-photos-api

I am attempting to verify that I have successfully copied a bunch of photos from google photos to onedrive. I can programmatically get the sha1 hash of each file stored in OneDrive but I don't see the same option from the google photos rest api. I would have expected it to be in the metadata: https://developers.google.com/photos/library/reference/rest/v1/mediaItems#MediaMetadata

It also doesn't look like the stored photos are exposed through the Google Drive api, so how do I get the hash?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the MD5 Checksum for the files stored on Google drive with the [Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list?apix_params=%7B%22fields%22%3A%22files(id%2C%20name%2C%20md5Checksum)%22%7D).

However, there is no way to get the SHA1 hash for files without downloading them.

Also, there is no way to get either of those with the Google Photos API.

Comment: You can go to the [Google Issue Tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker) and open one there.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can without downloading the photos - check rclone (listing as jsons returns the hashes)

https://rclone.org/commands/rclone_lsjson/

https://rclone.org/googlephotos/